# How to programmatically get exportable data for one particular fitness activity in Google Fit API?

Tags: google-fit

I require programmatic access to fitness activity data about activities in .fit, or any other popular format, which can plug into other popular services (like Strava). This is for a web app (not Android; Android docs seem to be more comprehensive), so I'm going through the REST API documentation by Google.

What I have been able to do thus far, is get a list of activities using the [Sessions List API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list).

```
{
  "deletedSession": [], 
  "nextPageToken": "1521908171108", 
  "session": [
    {
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1521394135119", 
      "endTimeMillis": "1521354180000", 
      "description": "", 
      "activityType": 7, 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.xiaomi.hm.health"
      }, 
      "startTimeMillis": "1521353940000", 
      "id": "Walk11521353940000", 
      "name": "Walk1"
    }, 
    {
     "modifiedTimeMillis": "1521908171107", 
     "endTimeMillis": "1521900180464", 
     "description": "", 
     "activityType": 8, 
     "application": {
       "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
     }, 
     "startTimeMillis": "1521898676234", 
     "id": "afe331980da3a28c:activemode:running:1521898676234", 
     "name": "Evening running"
   }
  ]
}
```

So now I have a list of these two activities. What I want now is detailed information about one of the activities, which I would then plug into some other service.

I've been going through the [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/) and have been unable to find anything about getting detailed data on activities.

So what I am looking for essentially is the feed that is in the structure attached here:

[image]

Any nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: When you say detailed activities, what data are you expecting?

Comment: @noogui I'm expecting something that can get me the equivalent .fit file or likewise. I intend to sync that data to other apps.

Comment: I've also update the question to reflect the desired feed type. I got this feed from Google's manual data export tool https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout